# Scraping threads that are hundreds of pages deep w/ BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Python and BeautifulSoup newbie here.

I am trying to scrape a forum that has about 500 pages, each of which contains 50 individual threads. Some of these threads contain about 200 pages worth of posts.

I would like to write a program that can scrape the relevant parts of the whole forum in an automated fashion, having been fed a single URL as an entry point:

```
    page_list = ['http://forum.doctissimo.fr/sante/diabete/liste_sujet-1.htm']
```

While I have no problem extracting the 'next link' for both the individual threads and the pages containing the threads... :

```
    def getNext_link(soup0bj):
       #extracts a page's next link from the Bsoup object 

       try:
          next_link = []
          soup0bj  = (soup0bj)
          for link in soup0bj.find_all('link', {'rel' : 'next'}):
             if link.attrs['href'] not in next_link:
                next_link.append(link.attrs['href'])

       return next_link
```

...I'm stuck with a program that takes that seeded URL and extracts contents only from the first pages of each thread that it hosts. The programme then ends:

```
     for page in page_list:
       if page != None: 
          html = getHTMLsoup(page)
          print(getNext_link(html))
          page_list.append(getNext_link(html))
          print(page_list)

          for thread in getThreadURLs(html):
             if thread != None:
                html = getHTMLsoup(thread)
                print('\n'.join(getHandles(html)))
                print('\n'.join(getTime_stamps(html)))
                print('\n', getNext_link(html))
                print('\n'.join(getPost_contents(html)),'\n')
```

I've tried appending the 'next link' into page_list, but that hasn't worked, as urlopen then tries to access a list rather than a string. I've also tried this:

```
    for page in itertools.chain(page_list):
```

...but the programme throws this error:

```
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'
```

I'm really stuck. Any and all help would be most welcome!

Comment: `for page in itertools.chain.from_iterable(page_list):`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, Padraic. Unfortunately, your suggestion results in the following error: ValueError: unknown url type: 'h'. Is there another way of doing this that I should look into?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this myself, so I'm posting the answer, just in case someone else might benefit.

So, the problem was that urlopen could not open the URL found in a list within a list.

In my case, each forum page had a maximum of 1 relevant internal link. Rather than asking my getNext_link function to return a list containing the internal link, as seen here (see empty list next_link)...

```
    def getNext_link(soup0bj):
        #extracts a page's next link (if available)

        try:
           soup0bj = (soup0bj)
           next_link = []

            if len(soup0bj.find_all('link', {'rel' : 'next'})) != 0:
              for link in soup0bj.find_all('link', {'rel' : 'next'}):
                 next_link.append(link.attrs['href'])

        return next_link
```

I asked it to return the URL as a string, as seen here:

```
    def getNext_link(soup0bj):

       try:
           soup0bj = (soup0bj)

            if len(soup0bj.find_all('link', {'rel' : 'next'})) != 0:
              for link in soup0bj.find_all('link', {'rel' : 'next'}):
                 next_link = link.attrs['href']
                 return next_link
```

As the variable next_link is simply a string, it can easily be added to a list that is being iterated over (see my post above for details). Voilà!